# Get Corba client activity on Server at runtime

Tags: java, logging, corba

I am a beginner with Corba. I have implement a small corba distributed application based on Java.

I want to know if there's any mechanism to get the clients IP and requests log on the server at runtime.

Comment: I'm surprised to read this.  I thought CORBA was a long-dead 90s technology.

Answer (score 0):

JacORB has support for a IIOPTransportCurrent, see [github](https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/blob/master/test/regression/src/test/java/org/jacorb/test/transport/IIOPTester.java) for an unit test as example.